# Markdown Reference Link with shields.io badges

Tags: html, github, markdown, readme, shields.io

How to make sure that the shields.io badge points to the site, and do that using reference-style markdown links.

This works fine

```
[![](https://img.shields.io/badge/code%20style-black-black.svg?style=for-the-badge&labelColor=gray)][http://github.com/psf/black]
```

[[image]][http://github.com/psf/black]

This doesn't works

```
![]([black-shield])[black]

[black]: http://github.com/psf/black
[black-shield]: https://img.shields.io/badge/code%20style-black-black.svg?style=for-the-badge&labelColor=gray
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works using square brackets!

[image]

```
[![][black-shield]][black]

[black]: http://github.com/psf/black
[black-shield]: https://img.shields.io/badge/code%20style-black-black.svg?style=for-the-badge&labelColor=gray
```

Answer (score 8):

The correct syntax is

```
[![General badge](https://img.shields.io/badge/<SUBJECT>-<STATUS>-<COLOR>.svg)](https://shields.io/)
```

**Example**

```
[![Stack Overflow Badge](https://img.shields.io/badge/Stack%20Overflow-F58025?logo=stackoverflow&logoColor=fff&style=flat)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299287/cryptocode)
```

**Produces**
[image: Stack Overflow Badge]

Comment: Thank you, but my objective was to use it with reference-style links

Comment: This works. I tested it just now. Thanks for this!